# Watch an Ethereum address for incoming payments

Tags: wallets, addresses

I want to watch a set of Ethereum contracts and be notified (preferably by email) when a contact receives a payment to it.

I prefer me not to write my own software for this and not to install it on my own server, but programming suggestions are welcome.

Comment: are those your own contracts or just any contracts you want to watch ?

Comment: @Cԃաԃ I created these smart contract myself, using my own software

Comment: I wrote an answer for a setup you could use, I'm currently running this setup myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the next setup.

1) in solidity inside of the payable function add event that will fire every time someone pays. for example : `PaymentReceived`

```
event PaymentReceived(address from, uint amount);
emit PaymentReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
```

2) start a nodejs server with `web3js` and watch for the event `PaymentReceived`
with web3js it will be something like this :

```
var ev = myContract.PaymentReceived({},{fromBlock:0, toBlock:'latest'});
ev.watch(function(error, result){
        if(!error){
                // send email here
        }else{

        }
});
```

3) you could use module like `shelljs` to run a script on linux to send email.

```
shell.exec('./sendEmailScript');
```

P.S. when watching for the event, you may want to use some sort of mechanism to check if you already send the notification email for a payment. Since every time you restart node application it will trigger send email script for every emit from solidity (because of this : `{fromBlock:0, toBlock:'latest'}`)
I would save it a database, say mysql with tx as unique key, and send email only if it hasn't been send already.